# UICollectionViewCell image reload issue after API call

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to load image for the particular cell for whose indexpath the URL is present. Have function to download the image and send it through call back method, but after callback the other cells are also getting loaded by the downloaded image. Thanks in Adv.

Here is the code sample. In method `cellForItemAtIndexPath`

```swift
let stationCollectionViewcell : StationCollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "stationCell", for: indexPath) as! StationCollectionViewCell

if imageURL.contains("http") {
    self.loadImageWithURL(url: URL(string: station.imageURL)!) { (image) in
        stationCollectionViewcell.radioImgView.image = image
    }
} else if imageURL != "" {
    stationCollectionViewcell.radioImgView.image = UIImage(named: "station-therockfm")
} else {
    stationCollectionViewcell.radioImgView.image = UIImage(named: "stationImage")
}
```

And the function that will download the image

```swift
func loadImageWithURL(url: URL, callback: @escaping (UIImage) -> ()) {
    print("This is getting excuted loadImageWithURL")
    let session = URLSession.shared
    let downloadTask = session.downloadTask(with: url, completionHandler: {
        url, response, error in
        
        if error == nil && url != nil {
            if let data = NSData(contentsOf: url!) {
                if let image = UIImage(data: data as Data) {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                        callback(image)
                    })
                }
            }
        }
    })
    downloadTask.resume()
}
```

Comment: Cells are reused. First reset the `radioImgView.image` to `nil` (or a placeholder).

Comment: @Larme tried this, but no luck, could you please give some example for this.

Answer (score 1):

You should reset `image` before reusing cell, because it is reused with previous image before new is downloaded. Also, you should compare saved url with url in callback, because callback may return when cell is reused.

```
// reset image 
override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()

    radioImgView.image = nil // set nil or default image
}
```

Add url to callback

```
func loadImageWithURL(url: URL, callback: @escaping (UIImage, URL) -> ()) {
print("This is getting excuted loadImageWithURL")
let session = URLSession.shared
let downloadTask = session.downloadTask(with: url, completionHandler: {
     url, response, error in

    if error == nil && url != nil {
        if let data = NSData(contentsOf: url!) {
            if let image = UIImage(data: data as Data) {
                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                    callback(image, url!)
                })
            }
        }
    }
})
     downloadTask.resume()
}
```

Compare url

```
let stationCollectionViewcell : StationCollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "stationCell", for: indexPath) as! StationCollectionViewCell

if imageURL.contains("http") {
   let url = URL(string: station.imageURL)!
   self.loadImageWithURL(url: url) { (image, callbackUrl) in
       guard url == callbackUrl else { return }
       stationCollectionViewcell.radioImgView.image = image
   }
} else if imageURL != "" {
   stationCollectionViewcell.radioImgView.image = UIImage(named: "station-therockfm")
} else {
   stationCollectionViewcell.radioImgView.image = UIImage(named: "stationImage")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Cells are reusing each time, also you have async call in the controller. In the downloading completion, you need to reload cell by `IndexPath`.

Also, reset image in `prepareForReuse`

```
 override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()

    stationCollectionViewcell.radioImgView.image = nil
}
```

The best solution with async images it's to have cache

```
let imageCache: NSCache<NSString, UIImage> = NSCache<NSString, UIImage>()
```

after loading has been completed save the image:

```
imageCache.setObject(image, forKey: url as NSString)
```

and next time, when cell appears, check is image already exists in `imageCache`

if yes, use image from the cache, if not, download an image
Code should looks like this:

```
if imageURL.contains("http") {
        if let image = imageCache.object(forKey: station.imageURL as NSString) {
            stationCollectionViewcell.radioImgView.image = image
        } else {
            self.loadImageWithURL(url: URL(string: station.imageURL)!) { [weak self] (image) in
                self?.imageCache.setObject(image, forKey: url as NSString)
                self?.collectionView.collectionView.reloadItems(at: [indexPath])
            }
        }


    } else if imageURL != "" {
        stationCollectionViewcell.radioImgView.image = UIImage(named: "station-therockfm")

    } else {
        stationCollectionViewcell.radioImgView.image = UIImage(named: "stationImage")

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**I hope, it will run Fine.**

```
import UIKit    

let imageCache = NSCache<AnyObject, AnyObject>()

class CustomImageView : UIImageView {

    var imgUrlString : String?

    func loadImageWithURL(urlString : String) {

        imgUrlString = urlString
        guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else { return }

        image = nil
        if let imgFromCache = imageCache.object(forKey: urlString as AnyObject) as? UIImage {
            self.image = imgFromCache
            return
        }

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, resposne, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print(error)
                return
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.sync {
                let imageToCache = UIImage(data: data!)
                imageCache.setObject(imageToCache!, forKey: urlString as AnyObject)
                if self.imgUrlString == urlString {
                    self.image = imageToCache
                }

            }

        }.resume()
    }
}
```

Intialize your instance with this Class.

```
let thumbnailImageView : CustomImageView = {
        let imgView = CustomImageView()
        imgView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        imgView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "taylor_swift_blank_space")
        imgView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        imgView.clipsToBounds = true
        return imgView
    }()
```